# Lacp limitations

Tags: cisco

I have a c3750g running three groups of ether channels, each with 4x1g interfaces.
I basically have my upstream connect to the switch via optical, then I take that to my router via 4 bonded port, then out again with 4 ports.
Then four more ports connect to a distribution CCR and I give to my clients via gepon and switch.
Now that the scenario has possibly confused you, the question is, why is my speed limited to 2.3 Gbps? 4 ports at 75% is 3.5g roughly.
Load balance is src-dst-ip, lacp passive.
Switch cpu at 5%

Comment: the only way to get a good answer is to capture some data with a tool like Wireshark and see whether you're dropping packets, or if this is a function of the receivers.  Do your interface counters show dropped packets?

Comment: Yes. Some output drops

Comment: It could be worth looking at different load-balancing options (src-dst-port, etc.).

Comment: Tried it but no go. Doesn't go over 2.3gbps. Waiting for a 10G direct connect cable. Don't see any other alternative at the moment. The other would be to get a ten g switch but that's not possible right now

Comment: Before you invest in 10G hardware, do some packet captures to make sure the limitations aren't due to your endpoints or application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is my speed limited to 2.3 Gbps?

Because LACP isn't "*additive*", it's a load balancing mechanism. The *src-dst-ip* hash will select only a single link, and all of the traffic between that src and dst will cross it. Thus, if you don't have a perfect distribution of src/dst pairs, some links will be more utilized than others.

Comment: Also, 2.3G is very close to the 2.5G signalling speed of GPON. (not sure if GEPON is the same)

Comment: Gepon is 3x1g-sfp uplink. But that had about 1.2g traffic. The rest goes through a sfp+ module of the ccr